# Angular Routing - Distinguish between new page request and navigation from different module

Tags: angular, routes

In my Angular app, I have a dashboard component that will be shown on the first page load. When the app is being loaded I want to show the user some tips to get him started. When he navigates to the dashboard from another component, I don't want to display those tips.

How can I differentiate between a new page request and the user navigating to the dashboard from a different page?

Answer (score 1):

We did it by placing resolvers in out code. It will resolve or execute before the route reach to the page. At that time you can check if the user is coming directly or from a different page. And as per that you can show the content

```
@Injectable()
export class DashResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                 state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | TitleResolverData {

    // this will give you weather you are coming from start or from another page
    if (!this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldAttach(route)) {
      return Observable.of(something);
    // you have data
    } else {
      return {
        title: 'Dashboard - ' + route.params.xxxx
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Adjust the code

And you can attach your route resolver

```
  resolve: {
    resolvedData: DashResolverService,
  }
```

These are the mothod available

```
*/
export declare abstract class RouteReuseStrategy {
    /** Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later */
    abstract shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean;
    /** Stores the detached route */
    abstract store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle | null): void;
    /** Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be reattached */
    abstract shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean;
    /** Retrieves the previously stored route */
    abstract retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null;
    /** Determines if a route should be reused */
    abstract shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean;
}
```